# Using Gdal on my mac high sierra

Tags: high-sierra, homebrew

I used to use smoothly Gdal on my mac from the terminal before the update to Mavericks. Since that, I have struggled. I am now using High Sierra, and my computer can't find the software. If I run:

```
brew install gdal
```

then I hit the problem

```
 brew already installed
```

Following the recommendations in https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/23424, I reinstalled it, unlinked it and relinked it. It still does not work. Please see picture. Has anyone experienced similar issues? DO you have a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste Terminal content, do not use screenshots (they don't work in search).

Comment: Also are you sure there even is a `gdal` command? I've just installed it, there is no `gdal` in `/usr/local/bin` nor in the Cellar.

Comment: @patrix: Yes, thank you. `which ogr2ogr` now did found the program. My mistake. I am still struggling to make my old programs work, but I think this might be a question for GIS-SE.

Answer (score 1):

The `gdal` package doesn't install a `gdal` binary:

```
pse@Mithos:~$ ll /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.2.4/bin
total 2088
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin   2203 May  4 11:52 gdal-config*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  39580 May  4 11:52 gdal_contour*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  34432 May  4 11:52 gdal_grid*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  35188 May  4 11:52 gdal_rasterize*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  40932 May  4 11:52 gdal_translate*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  40852 May  4 11:52 gdaladdo*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  38852 May  4 11:52 gdalbuildvrt*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  38672 May  4 11:52 gdaldem*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  41432 May  4 11:52 gdalenhance*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  34988 May  4 11:52 gdalinfo*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  46360 May  4 11:52 gdallocationinfo*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  34984 May  4 11:52 gdalmanage*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  39400 May  4 11:52 gdalserver*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  45936 May  4 11:52 gdalsrsinfo*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  45864 May  4 11:52 gdaltindex*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  40040 May  4 11:52 gdaltransform*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  39364 May  4 11:52 gdalwarp*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  40136 May  4 11:52 gnmanalyse*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  49772 May  4 11:52 gnmmanage*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  34624 May  4 11:52 nearblack*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  55228 May  4 11:52 ogr2ogr*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  46364 May  4 11:52 ogrinfo*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  69388 May  4 11:52 ogrlineref*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  50428 May  4 11:52 ogrtindex*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 verence  admin  35316 May  4 11:52 testepsg*
```

There is also no man page:

```
pse@Mithos:/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.2.4/share/man/man1$ ls
gdal-config.1       gdal_pansharpen.1   gdaladdo.1          gdalsrsinfo.1       ogr2ogr.1
gdal2tiles.1        gdal_polygonize.1   gdalbuildvrt.1      gdaltindex.1        ogr_utilities.1
gdal_calc.1         gdal_proximity.1    gdalcompare.1       gdaltransform.1     ogrinfo.1
gdal_contour.1      gdal_rasterize.1    gdaldem.1           gdalwarp.1          ogrlineref.1
gdal_edit.1         gdal_retile.1       gdalinfo.1          gnm_utilities.1     ogrmerge.1
gdal_fillnodata.1   gdal_sieve.1        gdallocationinfo.1  gnmanalyse.1        ogrtindex.1
gdal_grid.1         gdal_translate.1    gdalmanage.1        gnmmanage.1         pct2rgb.1
gdal_merge.1        gdal_utilities.1    gdalmove.1          nearblack.1         rgb2pct.1
```